# I'm trying to get the id when clicking different messages from sql database

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to get the id when I click different messages.

This is my javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#message-subject-result').click(function(){
      var message = document.getElementById('message_id').value;
      alert(message);

      });
 });
```

I am pulling it from a php function that is:

```
 <div id="message-subject-result">
 <div id="message-date">'.$date.'</div>
 <input type="hidden" id="message_id" value="'.$row['mes_id'].'"><div id="message-sender-name">FROM: '.$row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname'].'</div>
 <div id="message-subject">SUBJECT: '.$row['subject'].'</div>
 <div id="message-preview">'.$row['message'].'</div>
 </div>
```

The javascript works but only when I click on the first echoed result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is all your ids same??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace duplicating ids with classnames and use `find` method:

```
$('.message-subject-result').click(function() {
    var messageId = $(this).find('.message_id').val();
    alert(messageId);
});
```

valid HTML should be:

```
<div class="message-subject-result">
    <div clas="message-date">'.$date.'</div>
    <input type="hidden" class="message_id" value="'.$row['mes_id'].'">
    <div class="message-sender-name">FROM: '.$row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname'].'</div>
    <div class="message-subject">SUBJECT: '.$row['subject'].'</div>
    <div class="message-preview">'.$row['message'].'</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like your solution better. I always do it the way I illustrated with inline functions, but I always wondered how to get it by class.

Comment: This worked perfectly, I'm new at this javascript stuff! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must have all unique ids. Something like this will give you unique id's:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach($result as $row) { ?>
<div id="message-subject-result">
 <div id="message-date">'.$date.'</div>
 <input type="hidden" id="message_id<?php echo $i; ?>" value="'.$row['mes_id'].'"><div id="message-sender-name">FROM: '.$row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname'].'</div>
 <div id="message-subject">SUBJECT: '.$row['subject'].'</div>
 <div id="message-preview">'.$row['message'].'</div>
 </div>

<?php $i++;
 } ?>
```